# Creating a BST with each node having a key and name

Tags: java

I have been tasked to you use the names and surnames in
toSearchIn.txt
 in order
to tally and
print out,
the popularity of each of the names and
surnames in Bob’s friend list
.
Maintain two separate BSTs (one for names and one for surnames).
A node in the name BST stores a name, a counter for the num
ber of occurrences of that name, a key ( sum of chars of the name) and references to its left and right children
.
A node in the surname BST stores a surname, a counter for the number of occurrences of that
surname, a key (sum of chars
of the surname) and references to its left and right children.
Output
:
Traverse the name tree in order to print out each key, name and the number of occurrences of that name. Traverse the surname tree post order in order to print out the key,  surname and the number of occurrences of that surname.

So i got 3 classes and my code is supposed to print all the names, their keys and popularity but  it only prints 4 names.
Can anyone help me out??

here are my classes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BSTMain{
    public static ArrayList<String> names;
    public static ArrayList<String> surNames;
    public static  ArrayList<Integer> keys;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> keysNames;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> keysSurnames;
    public static void main(String args[]){
       keysNames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       keysSurnames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       BSTMethods treeName = new BSTMethods();
       BSTMethods treeSurname = new BSTMethods();
       BSTNode node = new BSTNode();
       names = new ArrayList<String>();
       surNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                //open textfiel and read names
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("toSearchIn.txt"));
            //iterate through the textfile to read fullnames
            while((reader.readLine()) != null){
                  String fullName = reader.readLine();
              //string becomes an array of 2 elements
              String[] array_fullName = new String[2];
              if(fullName != null)
              array_fullName = fullName.split(" ");
              else break;
              //first element in array is the name 
                  String name  = array_fullName[0];
              //adding the name to the array of names

              names.add(name);
              //2nd element in array becomes the surname
              String surname  = array_fullName[1];
              //adding the surname to the array of surnames
              surNames.add(surname);



                   }
         } 
        //File not a textfile
        catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
           }
        keysNames = BSTMethods.computeKey(names);
        keysSurnames = BSTMethods.computeKey(surNames);
        for(int i =0; i <(names.size()); i++) {
            treeName.addNode(keysNames.get(i), names.get(i));
        // System.out.println( names.get(i) );
            treeSurname.addNode(keysSurnames.get(i), surNames.get(i));
        // System.out.println( surNames.get(i) );

        }
        System.out.println("Name BST Traversed In Order");
        treeName.inOrder(treeName.root);
        System.out.println("**************************************************************\n");
        System.out.println("Surname BST Traversed Post Order");
        treeSurname.postOrder(treeSurname.root);











    }
}


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


    public class BSTMethods{
    private static  ArrayList<String> names;
    private static ArrayList<String> surNames;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public BSTNode root;
    public BSTNode parent;
    public BSTNode current;
    public BSTNode temp = root;

           BSTNode counter = new BSTNode();
          //keys ;  
      //adding keys method for names
      public static ArrayList<Integer> computeKey(ArrayList<String> names){
        int sum = 0;
        int char1 = 0;
         //determining keys for names and surnames
        for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
            //for each string name, process its characters and
             //work out int values
           for(int j = 1; j < (names.get(i)).length(); j++){
               //char at position 0
             char1 = (int)(names.get(i)).charAt(0);
                //summing the character int values
             sum = (char1) + (int)(names.get(i)).charAt(j); 
           }
             //and add to the keys' list
           keys.add(sum);
             //resetting sum
           sum = 0;

        }

        return keys;


      }
      public boolean addNode(int key, String name) {

         if(root == null) {
                root = new BSTNode(key, name); 
                temp = root;
                return true;
            }
            else if (key == temp.key){
                          temp.setCount();
                     return false;
         }
         else if (key <temp.key) {
                if(temp.left == null){
                    temp.left = new BSTNode(key, name);
                    return true;
                   } 
                   else {
                    temp = temp.left;
                        return addNode(key, name);
                 }
         }
         else if (key > temp.key) {
                 if (temp.right == null) {
                    temp.right = new BSTNode(key, name);
                    return true;
                  } 
                  else
                    return true;//addNode(key, name);

                    }
          else
              return false;

      } 

      public void inOrder (BSTNode x) {
        if(x == null) return ;
        if(x.left != null){
          inOrder(x.left);
        }
         System.out.println("key:"+ x.key + ", name:" + x.name + ", count:" + temp.count );
        if(x.right != null){
          inOrder(x.right);
        } 

      }

      public void postOrder (BSTNode y) {
        if(y.left != null){
         postOrder(y.left);
        }

        if(y.right != null){
          postOrder(y.right);
        }
        System.out.println("key:"+ y.key + ", surname:" + y.name + ", count:" + counter.getCount());  
      }

}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class BSTNode{

   public int count, key;
   public String name, surname;
   public  BSTNode left;
   public  BSTNode right;

    public BSTNode()
    {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public BSTNode(int key, String name) {

    this.key = key;
    this.name = name;

    }
    public void setCount()
    {
         count += 1;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.count;
    }



    public BSTNode getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BSTNode left)
    {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BSTNode getRight()
    {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BSTNode right)
    {
        this.right = right;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged through your code?

Comment: When insertin a key then the is equal to the current one, the names are similar I have to update my count and the one i have doesnt make sense

Comment: Yes i have, the problem seems to be with my recursive adding of nodes to my trees(addNode method)